# adding collision detection to j2me maze game

Tags: java-me, collision-detection, midp, lcdui

I am creating a maze game and I am using a 2d array to draw the maze. I have the maze drawn and the character moving around the place but I need to add some collision detection whenever the character hits a wall (the wall image is represented by the number 9 in the "map" array).

So basically what I want to do is detect if the "mQuatsch" is going to move into a part of the "map" array with the value 9 and if so, don't move

Does anyone know how to do this?

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.game.*;

public class QuatschCanvas
    extends GameCanvas
implements Runnable {
private boolean mTrucking;

private LayerManager mLayerManager;

private TiledLayer mAtmosphere;
private TiledLayer mBackground;
private int mAnimatedIndex;

private Sprite mQuatsch;
private int mState, mDirection;

private final int DOOR = 1;
private final int WALL = 9;
private final int KEY = 0;

private static final int kStanding = 1;
private static final int kRunning = 2;
private static final int kRunningUp = 3;
private static final int kRunningDown = 4;

private static final int kLeft = 1;
private static final int kRight = 2;
private static final int kUp = 3;
private static final int kDown = 4;

int [][] map = new int [8][7];

private static final int[] kRunningSequence = { 0, 1, 0, 2};
private static final int[] kStandingSequence = { 0 };
private static final int[] kRunningSequenceUp = { 3, 4, 3, 5};
private static final int[] kRunningSequenceDown = { 6, 7, 6, 8};

public QuatschCanvas(String quatschImageName,
  String atmosphereImageName, String backgroundImageName)
  throws IOException {
super(true);

// Create a LayerManager.
mLayerManager = new LayerManager();
int w = getWidth();
int h = getHeight();
mLayerManager.setViewWindow(96, 0, w, h);

createBackground(backgroundImageName);
createAtmosphere(atmosphereImageName);
createQuatsch(quatschImageName);
}

private void createBackground(String backgroundImageName)
  throws IOException {
// Create the tiled layer.
Image backgroundImage = Image.createImage(backgroundImageName);

//first 4 columns
map[0][0] = 9;  map[1][0] = 9;  map[2][0] = 9;  map[3][0] = 9;
map[0][1] = 9;  map[1][1] = 4;  map[2][1] = 4;  map[3][1] = 9;
map[0][2] = 9;  map[1][2] = 4;  map[2][2] = 4;  map[3][2] = 1;
map[0][3] = 9;  map[1][3] = 9;  map[2][3] = 9;  map[3][3] = 9;
map[0][4] = 9;  map[1][4] = 4;  map[2][4] = 1;  map[3][4] = 4;
map[0][5] = 9;  map[1][5] = 4;  map[2][5] = 9;  map[3][5] = 4;
map[0][6] = 9;  map[1][6] = 9;  map[2][6] = 9;  map[3][6] = 9;
//second 4 columns
map[4][0] = 9;  map[5][0] = 9;  map[6][0] = 9;  map[7][0] = 9;
map[4][1] = 4;  map[5][1] = 4;  map[6][1] = 4;  map[7][1] = 9;
map[4][2] = 4;  map[5][2] = 4;  map[6][2] = 4;  map[7][2] = 9;
map[4][3] = 9;  map[5][3] = 4;  map[6][3] = 9;  map[7][3] = 9;
map[4][4] = 4;  map[5][4] = 4;  map[6][4] = 4;  map[7][4] = 9;
map[4][5] = 4;  map[5][5] = 4;  map[6][5] = 4;  map[7][5] = 9;
map[4][6] = 9;  map[5][6] = 9;  map[6][6] = 9;  map[7][6] = 9;

mBackground = new TiledLayer(8, 7, backgroundImage, 96, 96);
mBackground.setPosition(12, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
  int column = i % 8;
  int row = j;
  mBackground.setCell(column, row, map[i][j]);
}
}
mAnimatedIndex = mBackground.createAnimatedTile(8);
//mBackground.setCell(3, 0, mAnimatedIndex);
//mBackground.setCell(5, 0, mAnimatedIndex);
mLayerManager.append(mBackground);
}

private void createAtmosphere(String atmosphereImageName)
  throws IOException {
// Create the atmosphere layer
Image atmosphereImage = Image.createImage(atmosphereImageName);
mAtmosphere = new TiledLayer(8, 1, atmosphereImage,
    atmosphereImage.getWidth(), atmosphereImage.getHeight());
mAtmosphere.fillCells(0, 0, 8, 1, 1);
mAtmosphere.setPosition(0,192 );

mLayerManager.insert(mAtmosphere, 0);
}

private void createQuatsch(String quatschImageName)
  throws IOException {
// Create the sprite.
Image quatschImage = Image.createImage(quatschImageName);
mQuatsch = new Sprite(quatschImage, 48, 48);
mQuatsch.setPosition(96 + (getWidth() - 48) / 2, 100);
mQuatsch.defineReferencePixel(24, 24);
setDirection(kLeft);
setState(kStanding);
mLayerManager.insert(mQuatsch, 1);
}

public void start() {
mTrucking = true;
Thread t = new Thread(this);
t.start();
}

public void run() {
int w = getWidth();
int h = getHeight();
Graphics g = getGraphics();
int frameCount = 0;
int factor = 2;
int animatedDelta = 0;

while (mTrucking) {
  if (isShown()) {
    int keyStates = getKeyStates();
    if ((keyStates & LEFT_PRESSED) != 0) {
      setDirection(kLeft);
      setState(kRunning);

      mBackground.move(3, 0);
      mAtmosphere.move(3, 0);
      mQuatsch.nextFrame();
    }
    else if ((keyStates & RIGHT_PRESSED) != 0) {
      setDirection(kRight);
      setState(kRunning);
      mBackground.move(-3, 0);
      mAtmosphere.move(-3, 0);
      mQuatsch.nextFrame();
    }
    else if ((keyStates & UP_PRESSED) != 0) {
      setDirection(kUp);
      setState(kRunningUp);
      mBackground.move(0, 3);
      mAtmosphere.move(0, 3);
      mQuatsch.nextFrame();
    }
    else if ((keyStates & DOWN_PRESSED) != 0) {
      setDirection(kDown);
      setState(kRunningDown);
      mBackground.move(0, -3);
      mAtmosphere.move(0, -3);
      mQuatsch.nextFrame();
    }
    else {
      setState(kStanding);
    }

    frameCount++;
    if (frameCount % factor == 0) {
      int delta = 1;
      if (frameCount / factor < 10) delta = -1;
      mAtmosphere.move(delta, 0);
      if (frameCount / factor == 20) frameCount = 0;

      mBackground.setAnimatedTile(mAnimatedIndex,
          8 + animatedDelta++);
      if (animatedDelta == 3) animatedDelta = 0;
    }

    g.setColor(0x5b1793);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

    mLayerManager.paint(g, 0, 0);

    flushGraphics();
  }

  try { Thread.sleep(80); }
  catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
}
}

public void stop() {
mTrucking = false;
}

public void setVisible(int layerIndex, boolean show) {
Layer layer = mLayerManager.getLayerAt(layerIndex);
layer.setVisible(show);
}

public boolean isVisible(int layerIndex) {
Layer layer = mLayerManager.getLayerAt(layerIndex);
return layer.isVisible();
}

private void setDirection(int newDirection) {
if (newDirection == mDirection) return;
if (mDirection == kLeft)
  mQuatsch.setTransform(Sprite.TRANS_MIRROR);
else if (mDirection == kRight)
  mQuatsch.setTransform(Sprite.TRANS_NONE);
mDirection = newDirection;
}

private void setState(int newState) {
if (newState == mState) return;
switch (newState) {
  case kStanding:
    mQuatsch.setFrameSequence(kStandingSequence);
    mQuatsch.setFrame(0);
    break;
  case kRunning:
    mQuatsch.setFrameSequence(kRunningSequence);
    break;
    case kRunningUp:
    mQuatsch.setFrameSequence(kRunningSequenceUp);
    break;
    case kRunningDown:
    mQuatsch.setFrameSequence(kRunningSequenceDown);
    break;
  default:
    break;
}
mState = newState;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:
http://j2medevcorner.wordpress.com/2007/03/29/collision-detection-in-j2me/

(I don't think all that code is needed for us to answer the question).

Comment: i understand the concept of collision detection, it is the coding i am having trouble with, im not sure which of the mQuatsch.collidiesWith() methods i should use and how to check if the player is about to step into a part of the map with the value of 9

Comment: I think you should use the one that takes a `TiledLayer`   http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/game/TiledLayer.html

Comment: but do you know how to implement it so that it detects a collision when you step into a cell with a particular value, like so,                                "if(mQuatsch.collidesWith(mBackground.getCell(4, 7), true)"